# How can i change the color of the background of a specific piece of text inside textarea?

Tags: html, css

I created a text area and tried to use span within it but the span tag is taken as a value.
Please help me out, my code was as follow -:

```
<textarea id="example"><span>This text's background need to be changed.</span>Not for this</textarea>
```

I used CSS for this.. but it didn't work out.

```
textarea{
background: red;
}
span{
background: yellow;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I wanted to change the background color of a specific piece of text within text area.. Is it possible ?

Comment: Whatever you write in between of `textarea` is considered as plain text(not html), so it is not possible to target `span` in `textarea`

Comment: yess.. thats what i want to know that is it even possible to do that